# Resolve warning "A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy"?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, conda

When I import SciPy or a library dependent on it, I receive the following warning message:

```
UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.23.1
```

It's true that I am running NumPy version 1.23.1, however this message is a mystery to me since I am running SciPy version 1.7.3, which, according to [SciPy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/dev/toolchain.html), is compatible with NumPy <1.24.0.

Anyone having this problem or know how to resolve it?

I am using Conda as an environment manager, and all my packages are up to date as far as I know.

- python: 3.9.12
- numpy: 1.23.1
- scipy: 1.7.3

Thanks in advance if anyone has any clues !

Comment: The documentation might just be wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the setup.py file of the scipy 1.7.3, numpy is indeed `<1.23.0`. As @Libra said, the docs must be incorrect. You can:

1. Ignore this warning
2. Use scipy 1.8
3. Use numpy < 1.23.0

**Edit**:

This is now fixed in the dev docs of scipy https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/toolchain.html

Comment: This answer could be improved by linking to the code where the specifications were found.

Comment: scipy 1.7.3 code [setup.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/59e6539cf80dc04b16b0f0ab52343381f0a7a2fa/setup.py#L552) and [\_\_init\_\_.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/59e6539cf80dc04b16b0f0ab52343381f0a7a2fa/scipy/__init__.py#L142)

Comment: @psarka, unfortunately for `conda` users that relies on channel `defaults` (because of Intel MKL setup) the `scipy` max version is still `1.7.3`.  In the channel `conda-forge` it's already `1.9.0` (which requires `numpy >=1.18.5, <1.25.0`).  There seems to be a relevant MKL configuration difference if one checks `numpy.show_config()` and `scipy.show_config()`.  I need to test with the channel `conda-forge` and the Mutex metapackage `"blas=*=mkl"` to see if MKL would peform the same, see [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/packages.html#mutex-metapackages).

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue.

The [scipy 1.7.3 docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/dev/toolchain.html#numpy) specifies
`1.16.5 <= numpy <1.24.0` while in scipy 1.7.3 code [setup.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/59e6539cf80dc04b16b0f0ab52343381f0a7a2fa/setup.py#L552) and [__init__.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/59e6539cf80dc04b16b0f0ab52343381f0a7a2fa/scipy/__init__.py#L142) we have `np_maxversion = '1.23.0'`.

As I rely on `conda channel defaults` to setup Intel MKL libraries for numpy and scipy I decided to pin `"numpy>=1.22.3,<1.23.0"` until a newer scipy is release on `conda channel defaults`:

```
conda create -n myenv python "numpy>=1.22.3,<1.23.0" scipy
```

Comment: How can I achieve this in Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: As far as I know the navigator doesn't allow you to specify a version range but you can select a specific one that attends the requirement above:

1) select an environment  
2) right-click the package name  
3) choose "Mark for a specific version installation"  
4) select (the highest) `numpy` version within the required range (currently just the `1.22.3` from defaults channel)

Answer (score 5):

Since "*UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required*", you can update the numpy version with the specified range to remove the warning.

According to syntax guidelines of [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/_downloads/843d9e0198f2a193a3484886fa28163c/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) and [pip](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-pypi), updating your numpy version by

`conda install "numpy>=1.16.5,<1.23.0"`

or

`pip install "numpy>=1.16.5,<1.23.0"`

inside your environment will work.

Your numpy will be overwritten by the best-match version (`1.22.4`) in the specified range. You can double-check the new numpy version by:

`conda list numpy`

or

`pip show numpy`

Answer (score 0):

For my similar problem pip install "numpy>=1.16.5,<1.23.0"
That works too.